# VM Logical Volume shown on Host

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, opennebula

Some context, I've builded an Opennebula cloud (https://opennebula.io/). I've been using it for more than 2 years now without any issue on that side. Recently i've noticed a strange behavior.

On my hypervisor which are the servers who are running libvirt and the KVM I am able to see to logical volume of a guest. Morever as I am using an LVM datastores to operate Opennebula I see all logical volume of all the recent guest.( This does not apply for the old VMs)

Here the example.

```
root@xxx:/home/xxe# lvs
  LV           VG            Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
                                              
  THIS IS NOT EXPECTED                                                 
  image        on-disk       -wi-------  140,00g                                                    
  lv-mysql     on-disk       -wi-------  <25,00g                                                    
  data         opt           -wi-----p-   29,99g                                                    
  data         opt           -wi-------  <50,00g                                                    
  data         sql           -wi-------  <50,00g                                                    
  image        vg-one-101    -wi-------  190,00g   
  

  THIS IS EXPECTED
  lv-one-164-0 vg-one-104    -wi-a-----   24,00g                                                    
  lv-one-167-0 vg-one-104    -wi-a-----  <24,59g                                                    
  lv-one-167-2 vg-one-104    -wi-a-----   50,00g                                                    
  lv-one-167-3 vg-one-104    -wi-a-----   50,00g                                                    
  lv-one-168-0 vg-one-104    -wi-ao----  <24,59g                                                    
  lv-one-168-2 vg-one-104    -wi-ao----  100,00g                                                    
  lv-one-173-0 vg-one-104    -wi-ao----  <24,59g                                                    
  lv-one-174-0 vg-one-104    -wi-ao----  <24,59g                                                    
  lv-one-174-2 vg-one-104    -wi-ao----  120,00g
```

Not really asking on Opennebula way of working but more around KVM.  Why for some and only some of the guest logical volume are displayed on the host ?